# Elementary (fundamental) properties in electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, elementary-particles

I tend to believe that there are two elementary properties in electricity:

1. Electric charge
2. Coulomb's force

I think that I can express any other entity in electricity using just these two (by means of other physical theories e.g. relativity).

Am I correct, or there are properties which can't be expressed in terms of the above two? Are these really elementary, or they can be expressed in terms of more elementary properties?

Comment: What is your definition of an entity? A mathematical expression? A fundamental property?

Comment: How about this: entity = fundamental property which must be measured and can't be derived from more fundamental properties. Tell me whether this sounds reasonable and I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these really elementary, or they can be expressed in terms of more
>   elementary entities?

Well, consider that, for example, according to the Standard Model, electric charge is a particular mixture of [weak isospin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin) and [weak hypercharge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge):

From Wiki:

> Electric charge, $Q$, is related to weak isospin, $T_3$, and weak
>   hypercharge, $Y_W$, by
>
> $Q = T_3 + \frac{Y_\mathrm{W}}{2}$

I'm not sure that "entity" is correct here though.  Perhaps "property"?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental property allowing matter to interact through electricity is charge. In classical electromagnetism, there are two distinct kinds of effects caused by charge: the electric and the magnetic field. The former is sourced by a static charge while the latter is a result of moving charge (current). Special relativity tells us that both are just different aspects of the electromagnetic field. The electric field is therefore not more fundamental than the magnetic.

To conclude: if you want fundamental, measurable quantities related to electromagnetism, I would name charge, the speed of light (which is crucial to the relativistic approach) and, depending on definitions, the [permitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity) and [permeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_constant) in vacuum.